# Find global minimum of equation with many local minima

Tags: mathematical-optimization

How can I find global minimum for the function: (what is the function name?)

```
ff[x_] := 0.01*(x + 20) + 0.001*(x + 20)^2 + Sin[(x + 20)] + 20

Plot[ff[x],{x,-222,222}]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could use a function like FindMinimum, or perhaps NMinimize?

Comment: Welcome! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e it arises from a simply not readfing the documentation and is unlikely to help any future visitors. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397).

Comment: Learn abut [Numerical and Symbolic Optimization here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Optimization.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is a parabola plus a sinusoidal. The parabola has minimum at `x-> -25` that you can find like this

```
Minimize[0.01*(x + 20) + 0.001*(x + 20)^2 + 20, x]
```

> ```
> {19.975, {x -> -25.}}
> ```

or

```
Solve[D[0.01*(x + 20) + 0.001*(x + 20)^2 + 20, x] == 0, x]
```

> ```
>  {{x -> -25.}}
> ```

For your particular function, there will be many local minima, so the initial guess is important. here I use [`FindMinimum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html) with an initial guess given by the minimum of the parabola.

```
{x, ff[x]} /. FindMinimum[ff[x], {x, -25}][[2]]
```

> ```
> {-27.8483, 18.9831}
> ```

Or you could use [`Minimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html) giving constrains around `x->-25`. Notice that without constrains it will not find the global minimum.

```
Minimize[{ff[x], -50 < x < 0}, x]
```

> ```
> {18.9831, {x -> -27.8483}}
> ```

you can see the result in a [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) by placing a [`Point`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Point.html) in an [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)

```
Plot[ff[x], {x, -50, 0}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{x, ff[x]} /. FindMinimum[ff[x], {x, -25}][[2]]]}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

As a supplement to the solution of rhermans

```
ff[x_]= 0.01*(x + 20) + 0.001*(x + 20)^2 + Sin[(x + 20)] + 20;
tab = Table[{x, ff[x]}, {x, -222, 222, 0.001}];
{x, ff} = MinimalBy[tab, Last] // Flatten
{-27.848, 18.9831}
```